# HD Windows 7 IDE to AHCI on Windows 8.1 SSD

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, ssd, ahci

I have Windows 8.1 installed in a SSD as AHCI. I installed Windows without any other hard drive connected to the MB. I have my old hard drive of 1TB with Windows 7 installed in IDE mode. I connected this hard drive into my new PC, but Windows doesn't recognize it. I know that it's possible to change IDE to AHCI without having to reinstall Windows, but I want to know if I'll be enable to see this hard drive on my new PC.

Comment: There are tons of questions on how to switch it.

Comment: I think the question is if i convert my old HD into windows 7 for work in AHCI the new PC with works in AHCI will recognize this old HD that have windows 7 installed, i just wants to get the files e clean the old HD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disconnect the SSD and connect only the HDD. Now go into the BIOS and change the SATA Mode to IDE. Now boot the Windows 7 (in IDE mode) and run [this FixIt to configure loading AHCI drivers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976).

Now shutdown Windows 7, go to the BIOS and enable AHCI again. Now you can also connect the SSD again and select in Bootmanager of the motherboard (<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>) which Windows you want to boot.